# Turn off automatic updates on Debian/KDE5

Tags: linux, debian, kde, automatic-update, kde-plasma-5

I cannot figure out how to turn off automatic updates in Debian buster running KDE. I've gone into the "apper" control screen and set to "never", but still I keep getting a little taskbar icon on the bottom that tells me I have updates with the discover tool, and while that's in motion, I can't use command line tools to upgrade.

[This solution](https://superuser.com/questions/267302/disable-automated-updates-and-notifications-in-kde-debian#267310) only seems to work for KDE4.5, not the newer KDE5.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only viable solution seems to be  to uninstall `plasma-discover`.
This is suggested in several posts, for example at the [KDE Forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=138765).

One user described in the same thread, how to disable the automatic updates via Muon:

> Software Sources > Updates > and deselect "Check for updates"

I could not reproduce this solution, as in my settings the checkbox was already deselected and I received still update notifications.